# Why the sum of deformations in given figure is zero?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, statics

When a vertical block is kept between two fixed support and when the bottom support is removed, it has the possibility of facing a deformation downwards which was impeded by the upward reaction force of the fixed support. I know that this fact may be availed to solve statically indeterminate problems. I face doubt in a problem based on the same idea.

With respect to the following free body diagram (Fig. 2.23) of the components of the structure given below it, it has been mentioned that

Deformation in (b) + Deformation in (c) = 0

How is this possible, considering they are on different components and hence need not be equal to zero ?

[image][image]

Comment: In the diagram to the left of example 2.03 if the bottom pin is removed the problem is statically determinate not statically indeterminate

Comment: @Bob D The problem might be an example to show how to solve using the idea of deformations.